Stein-Tomas restriction theorem
The Stein-Tomas restriction theorem says that:
If $f$ is in $L^p\left(\mathbf{R}^n\right)$ for some $p$ with $1 \leqslant p<2(n+1) /(n+3)$, then
$\int_{S^{n-1}}|\hat{f}(\theta)|^2 d \theta \leqslant c_p\|f\|_p^2 .$
My question how is defined here the Fourier transform.

It's the Fourier transform of $f$ as a tempered distribution on $\mathbb R^n.$ In general, the Fourier transform of an $L^p$ function (considered as a tempered distribution) is not even a function on $\mathbb R^n.$ For $p\leq 2,$ however, it is an $L^q$ function (where $p^{-1}+q^{-1}=1$).
It is nontrivial to establish that this $L^q$ function, a priori only defined up to a subset of Lebesgue measure zero in $\mathbb R^n,$ is actually well-defined on the sphere (almost everywhere with respect to the area measure), but that is part of the fun of these restriction theorems. This is clearly false, for example, in the case $p=q=2$ (not covered by Stein-Tomas) because the Fourier transform is an isometry of $L^2.$

Thank you for your answer, Please is there a good reference there?

why the LHS is well-defined on the sphere?

Have a look at Loukas Grafakos' work that appears nowadays as 2 separate volumes (nos. 249-250) in the Springer GTM series: "Classical Fourier Analysis" and "Modern Fourier Analysis". Section 2.2.4 in the former describes the Fourier transform on the space $L^1(\mathbb R^n)+L^2(\mathbb R^n)$ and why the result is still a function. Section 10.4 in the latter explains why the Fourier transform of some $L^p$ functions is well-defined even on some subsets of measure $0$ like the sphere. But you asked about Stein-Tomas yourself: surely you must have a reference where it is mentioned.

An elementary case is $p=1.$ The Fourier transform of such a function is not only in $L^\infty,$ i.e., essentially uniformly bounded; it is also uniformly continuous and therefore defined everywhere, not merely almost everywhere with respect to Lebesgue measure.

Thank you for your help
